# adjust column width in wide table

Tags: tabularx

I would like to adjust the columns width. My table have 15 columns, I tried tabularx but it sent me an error. Any help or advice please.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{book}
\usepackage[small,pagestyles, clearempty, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}


\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,makecell,booktabs,rotating,ltablex}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm,amsthm,amscd,ragged2e,booktabs,changepage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headsep=1cm,right=2cm,vscale=0.75]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
    \centering\footnotesize
    \caption{Régression des rendements sur facteur}
    \label{sent-125}{\textbf{Estimation du Pouvoir Prédictif du facteur }} \\


    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{14}{Y}}
            \multicolumn{14}{l}{Régression de l’excès de rendement du marché (S\&P500 EW) sur le facteur d’une période :} \\
            \multicolumn{14}{c}{\begin{equation*}r_{t} = \alpha+ + \epsilon_{t}\end{equation*}}\\
            \multicolumn{14}{l}{La fréquence des données est mensuelle. $r_t$ dénote le rendement en excès du marché calculé sur l’indice composite S\&P500, }\\
            \toprule

        ~ ~        & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{S}$}  &\mc{$\hat{\beta}_{H}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{L}$}  & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{UM}$}   & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{CI}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{FS}$}  & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{V}$}   & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{AA}$} & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{II}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{CR}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{M}$}      & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT1}$}  & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT2}$}  & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT3}$}    \\ 
        \midrule
        ~smb       & 7.396      & 7.379      & 2.860      & 0.447     & 6.984      & 38.767**  & -13.809*   & -7.895     & 5.046      & -16.538**  & 24.787*   & -8.723    & -16.538**  & 40.769**   \\
        ~          & (1.301)    & (1.299)    & (0.475)    & (0.064)   & (1.203)    & (2.133)   & (-1.917)   & (-1.048)   & (0.842)    & (-2.052)   & (1.794)   & (-1.165)  & (-2.052)   & (2.367)    \\
        ~hml       & 5.589      & 5.611      & 3.327      & 5.524     & 5.818      & 40.218**  & 31.466***  & 26.401***  & 4.901      & 36.569***  & 46.869*** & 29.023*** & 36.569***  & 40.416**   \\
        ~          & (0.690)    & (0.693)    & (0.383)    & (0.595)   & (0.711)    & (2.360)   & (3.212)    & (2.618)    & (0.583)    & (3.548)    & (3.517)   & (2.889)   & (3.548)    & (2.466)    \\
        ~RMW       & -0.307***  & -0.288***  & -0.312***  & -0.338*** & -0.287***  & -1.234*** & -0.580***  & -0.496***  & -0.296***  & -0.684***  & -0.811*** & -0.513*** & -0.684***  & -1.169***  \\
        ~          & (-3.848)   & (-3.613)   & (-3.707)   & (-3.768)  & (-3.593)   & (-4.503)  & (-6.304)   & (-5.101)   & (-3.622)   & (-6.664)   & (-4.444)  & (-5.323)  & (-6.664)   & (-4.344)   \\
        ~CMA       & -0.820***  & -0.799***  & -0.884***  & -0.785*** & -0.835***  & -0.495    & -0.814***  & -0.859***  & -0.825***  & -0.708***  & -0.500**  & -0.884*** & -0.708***  & -0.531*    \\
        ~          & (-7.292)   & (-7.080)   & (-7.442)   & (-6.130)  & (-7.356)   & (-1.605)  & (-6.376)   & (-6.372)   & (-6.934)   & (-5.224)   & (-2.174)  & (-6.612)  & (-5.224)   & (-1.771)   \\
        ~umd       & -12.971*** & -12.961*** & -13.173*** & -10.169** & -12.666*** & -11.162   & -16.585*** & -13.009*** & -13.482*** & -17.187*** & -9.915    & -11.852** & -17.187*** & -4.792     \\
        ~          & (-3.361)   & (-3.361)   & (-3.263)   & (-2.342)  & (-3.228)   & (-1.385)  & (-3.762)   & (-2.822)   & (-3.392)   & (-3.748)   & (-1.451)  & (-2.588)  & (-3.748)   & (-0.596)   \\
        ~SBBB\_l1   & 0.127      & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & (0.779)    & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~HHHH\_l1  & ~          & -0.195     & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & (-1.201)   & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~LuUU\_l1  & ~          & ~          & 0.427*     & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & (1.749)    & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~UMMM\_l1  & ~          & ~          & ~          & 0.859     & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & (0.597)   & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~CCC\_l1   & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & -0.423     & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & (-0.643)   & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~FFFF\_l1 & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & -0.323    & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & (-0.801)  & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~VVV\_l1   & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & 0.473      & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & (0.176)    & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~AAAA\_l1  & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & -0.528     & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & (-0.326)   & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~IIII\_l1    & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & -1.470     & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & (-1.169)   & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~CRCR\_l1   & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & -0.127     & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & (-0.113)   & ~         & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~MS\_l1    & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & -0.501*   & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & (-1.673)  & ~         & ~          & ~          \\
        ~SENT1\_L1  & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & -0.473**  & ~          & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & (-2.326)  & ~          & ~          \\
        ~SENT2\_l1 & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & -0.025     & ~          \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & (-0.113)   & ~          \\
        ~SENT3\_l1 & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & -0.881**   \\
        ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~         & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~          & ~         & ~         & ~          & (-2.177)   \\
        \hline
        ~\_cons    & 0.917***   & 0.905***   & 0.756***   & 0.353     & 1.347**    & 0.644     & 1.140**    & 1.272      & 1.859**    & 1.117      & 0.709**   & 0.957***  & 1.010***   & 0.619      \\
        ~          & (5.536)    & (5.462)    & (3.666)    & (0.283)   & (2.109)    & (1.611)   & (2.043)    & (1.382)    & (2.404)    & (1.150)    & (2.534)   & (4.704)   & (4.500)    & (1.584)    \\
        ~Obs.      & 618        & 618        & 530        & 479       & 610        & 90        & 335        & 365        & 582        & 266        & 144       & 365       & 266        & 90         \\
        ~R-squared & 0.184      & 0.185      & 0.211      & 0.177     & 0.188      & 0.463     & 0.288      & 0.228      & 0.188      & 0.323      & 0.394     & 0.240     & 0.323      & 0.488      \\
        \multicolumn{15}{l}{~}                                                                                                                                                                       \\ 
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{14}{l}{T-values are in  parenthesis}                                                                                                                                             \\
        \multicolumn{14}{l}{*** p\textless{}0.01, ** p\textless{}0.05, * p\textless{}0.1}                                                                                                           
    \end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What does (do) the error message(s) say?

Comment: Missing $ inserted. \end{tabularx}

Comment: X Columns too narrow (table too wide)(tabularx), Overfull \hbox (11.96179pt too wide) in paragraph

Comment: Two observations: you should put your table in a `landscape`  environment and adopt the syntax of `longtable` (no table environment, `caption` in the `\firsthead section) Also, no `\centering`: this is automatic. Unrelated: `fancyheadings` should be replaced with `fancyhdr`. The former has been obsolete for more than 30 years. Also `aeguill` shouldn't be used any more.

Comment: you can not do `\multicolumn{14}{c}{\begin{equation*}r_{t} = \alpha+ + \epsilon_{t}\end{equation*}}` the column `c`  is hmode, like `\mbox`  so can not have display math environments

Answer (score 6):

Your table is to huge that can be fit in one page even in landscape orientation. Beside this, in you code are some errors and my clutter. For example, display math equation can not be in cell defined as `c` column type, ˙~` is not needed in empty cells etc. For columns is better to use type which enable aligning at decimal points

As starting point to improve your table can serve the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{book}
\usepackage[small,pagestyles, clearempty, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}


\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,makecell,booktabs,rotating,tabularx}%,ltablex
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
%\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm,amsthm,amscd,ragged2e,booktabs,changepage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headsep=1cm,right=2cm,vscale=0.75]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering\scriptsize
    \caption{Régression des rendements sur facteur}
    \label{sent-125}
\sisetup{table-space-text-pre={(},
         table-align-text-pre=false,
         table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},
         table-align-text-post=false,
         input-open-uncertainty = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-format=-2.3
         }

    \textbf{Estimation du Pouvoir Prédictif du facteur}

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\raggedright
Régression de l’excès de rendement du marché (S\&P500 EW) sur le facteur d’une période:
$
r_{t} = \alpha + \epsilon_{t}
$
La fréquence des données est mensuelle. $r_t$ dénote le rendement en excès du marché calculé sur l’indice composite S\&P500,              
\end{minipage}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.9}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} c *{14}{S} @{}}
            \toprule
    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{S}$}        &\mc{$\hat{\beta}_{H}$}     & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{L}$}  
    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{UM}$}       & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{CI}$}   & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{FS}$}  
    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{V}$}        & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{AA}$}   & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{II}$}    
    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{CR}$}       & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{M}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT1}$}  
    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT2}$}    & \mc{$\hat{\beta}_{SENT3}$}    \\
        \midrule
smb     & 7.396         & 7.379     & 2.860      & 0.447     & 6.984      & 38.767**  & -13.809*
        & -7.895        & 5.046     & -16.538**  & 24.787*   & -8.723    & -16.538**  & 40.769**   \\
        & (1.301)       & (1.299)   & (0.475)    & (0.064)   & (1.203)    & (2.133)   & (-1.917)           & (-1.048)        & (0.842) & (-2.052)   & (1.794)   & (-1.165)  & (-2.052)   & (2.367)    \\
hml     & 5.589         & 5.611     & 3.327      & 5.524     & 5.818      & 40.218**  & 31.466***  
        & 26.401***     & 4.901     & 36.569***  & 46.869*** & 29.023*** & 36.569***  & 40.416**   \\
        & (0.690)       & (0.693)   & (0.383)    & (0.595)   & (0.711)    & (2.360)   & (3.212)    
        & (2.618)       & (0.583)   & (3.548)    & (3.517)   & (2.889)    & (3.548)   & (2.466)    \\
RMW     & -0.307***     & -0.288*** & -0.312***  & -0.338*** & -0.287***  & -1.234*** & -0.580***  
        & -0.496***     & -0.296*** & -0.684***  & -0.811*** & -0.513***  & -0.684*** & -1.169***  \\
        & (-3.848)      & (-3.613)  & (-3.707)   & (-3.768)  & (-3.593)   & (-4.503)  & (-6.304)   
        & (-5.101)      & (-3.622)  & (-6.664)   & (-4.444)  & (-5.323)   & (-6.664)  & (-4.344)   \\
CMA     & -0.820***     & -0.799*** & -0.884***  & -0.785*** & -0.835***   & -0.495    & -0.814*** 
        & -0.859***     & -0.825*** & -0.708***  & -0.500**  & -0.884*** & -0.708***  & -0.531*    \\
        & (-7.292)      & (-7.080)  & (-7.442)   & (-6.130)  & (-7.356)   & (-1.605)  & (-6.376)   
        & (-6.372)      & (-6.934)  & (-5.224)   & (-2.174)  & (-6.612)  & (-5.224)   & (-1.771)   \\
umd     & -12.971***    & -12.961***& -13.173*** & -10.169** & -12.666*** & -11.162   & -16.585*** 
        & -13.009***    & -13.482***& -17.187*** & -9.915    & -11.852** & -17.187*** & -4.792     \\
        & (-3.361)      & (-3.361)  & (-3.263)   & (-2.342)  & (-3.228)   & (-1.385)  & (-3.762)   
        & (-2.822)      & (-3.392)  & (-3.748)   & (-1.451)  & (-2.588)  & (-3.748)   & (-0.596)   \\
SBBB\_l1    & 0.127     &           &           &           &           &           &
            &           &           &           &           &           &           &            \\
        & (0.779)       &           &           &           &           &           &
        &               &           &           &           &           &           &            \\
HHHH\_l1    &           & -0.195    &           &           &           &           &
            &           &           &           &           &           &           &            \\
        &           & (-1.201)   &            &           &            &            &
        &           &            &            &           &            &            &            \\
LuUU\_l1    &       &            & 0.427*     &           &            &           &
            &       &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
        &           &            & (1.749)    &           &            &           &
        &           &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
UMMM\_l1    &           &            &            & 0.859     &         &           &
            &           &            &            &           &         &           &            \\
        &            &            &            & (0.597)   &            &           &
        &            &            &            &           &            &           &            \\
CCC\_l1     &            &            &            &           & -0.423     &           &
            &            &            &            &           &           &            &       \\
        &            &            &            &           & (-0.643)   &           &
        &            &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
FFFF\_l1 &            &            &            &           &            & -0.323    &            &            &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            & (-0.801)  &            &            &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
VVV\_l1   &            &            &            &           &            &           & 0.473      &            &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           & (0.176)    &            &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
AAAA\_l1  &            &            &            &           &            &           &            & -0.528     &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            & (-0.326)   &            &            &           &           &            &            \\
IIII\_l1    &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            & -1.470     &            &           &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            & (-1.169)   &            &           &           &            &            \\
CRCR\_l1   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            & -0.127     &           &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            & (-0.113)   &           &           &            &            \\
MS\_l1    &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            & -0.501*   &           &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            & (-1.673)  &           &            &            \\
SENT1\_L1  &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           & -0.473**  &            &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           & (-2.326)  &            &            \\
SENT2\_l1 &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           &           & -0.025     &            \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           &           & (-0.113)   &            \\
SENT3\_l1 &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           &           &            & -0.881**   \\
                   &            &            &            &           &            &           &            &            &            &            &           &           &            & (-2.177)   \\
        \hline
\_cons    & 0.917***   & 0.905***   & 0.756***   & 0.353     & 1.347**    & 0.644     & 1.140**    & 1.272      & 1.859**    & 1.117      & 0.709**   & 0.957***  & 1.010***   & 0.619      \\
                   & (5.536)    & (5.462)    & (3.666)    & (0.283)   & (2.109)    & (1.611)   & (2.043)    & (1.382)    & (2.404)    & (1.150)    & (2.534)   & (4.704)   & (4.500)    & (1.584)    \\
Obs.    & {618}     & {618}     & {530}     & {479}     & {610}     & {90}      & {335}
        & {365}     & {582}     & {266}     & {144}     & {365}     & {266}     & {90}          \\
R-squared & 0.184      & 0.185      & 0.211      & 0.177     & 0.188      & 0.463     & 0.288      & 0.228      & 0.188      & 0.323      & 0.394     & 0.240     & 0.323      & 0.488      \\
        \bottomrule
        \multicolumn{15}{l}{T-values are in  parenthesis}           \\
        \multicolumn{15}{l}{*** $p<0.01$, ** $p<0.05$, * p$<0.1$}
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you load the `rotating` package, you might as well employ a `sidewaystable` environment to typeset the table in landscape format. Since none of the columns require automatic line wrapping, I would also like to suggest that you employ a `tabular*` environment instead of the `tabularx` environment.

Oh, do align the numbers in the 14 data columns on their respective decimal markers, and don't load packages more than once.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{book}
\usepackage[small,pagestyles, clearempty, explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[cyr]{aeguill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%%%{fancyheadings}
%%%%%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array,makecell,booktabs,rotating,ltablex}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,bm,amsthm,amscd,ragged2e,%%%booktabs,
    changepage}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%%%%%\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
%%%%%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm,headsep=1cm,hmargin=2cm,vscale=0.75,]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\newcommand\hbeta{\hat{\beta}}

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}
%\centering
\scriptsize
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\caption{Régression des rendements sur facteur}\label{sent-125}

Régression de l’excès de rendement du marché (S\&P500 EW) sur le facteur d’une période:
\[
r_{t} = \alpha+ + \epsilon_{t}
\]
La fréquence des données est mensuelle. $r_t$ dénote le rendement en excès du marché calculé sur l’indice composite S\&P500,

Estimation du Pouvoir Prédictif du facteur

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{14}{d{2.6}} }
\addlinespace
\toprule

& \mc{$\hbeta_{S}$}  & \mc{$\hbeta_{H}$}  & \mc{$\hbeta_{L}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{UM}$} 
& \mc{$\hbeta_{CI}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{FS}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{V}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{AA}$} 
& \mc{$\hbeta_{II}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{CR}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{M}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{SENT1}$} 
& \mc{$\hbeta_{SENT2}$} & \mc{$\hbeta_{SENT3}$} \\ 
\midrule
smb & 7.396 & 7.379 & 2.860 & 0.447 & 6.984 & 38.767^{**} & -13.809^{*} & -7.895 & 5.046 & -16.538^{**} & 24.787^{*} & -8.723 & -16.538^{**} & 40.769^{**} \\
 & (1.301) & (1.299) & (0.475) & (0.064) & (1.203) & (2.133) & (-1.917) & (-1.048) & (0.842) & (-2.052) & (1.794) & (-1.165) & (-2.052) & (2.367) \\
 hml & 5.589 & 5.611 & 3.327 & 5.524 & 5.818 & 40.218^{**} & 31.466^{***} & 26.401^{***} & 4.901 & 36.569^{***} & 46.869^{***} & 29.023^{***} & 36.569^{***} & 40.416^{**} \\
 & (0.690) & (0.693) & (0.383) & (0.595) & (0.711) & (2.360) & (3.212) & (2.618) & (0.583) & (3.548) & (3.517) & (2.889) & (3.548) & (2.466) \\
 RMW & -0.307^{***} & -0.288^{***} & -0.312^{***} & -0.338^{***} & -0.287^{***} & -1.234^{***} & -0.580^{***} & -0.496^{***} & -0.296^{***} & -0.684^{***} & -0.811^{***} & -0.513^{***} & -0.684^{***} & -1.169^{***} \\
 & (-3.848) & (-3.613) & (-3.707) & (-3.768) & (-3.593) & (-4.503) & (-6.304) & (-5.101) & (-3.622) & (-6.664) & (-4.444) & (-5.323) & (-6.664) & (-4.344) \\
 CMA & -0.820^{***} & -0.799^{***} & -0.884^{***} & -0.785^{***} & -0.835^{***} & -0.495 & -0.814^{***} & -0.859^{***} & -0.825^{***} & -0.708^{***} & -0.500^{**} & -0.884^{***} & -0.708^{***} & -0.531^{*} \\
 & (-7.292) & (-7.080) & (-7.442) & (-6.130) & (-7.356) & (-1.605) & (-6.376) & (-6.372) & (-6.934) & (-5.224) & (-2.174) & (-6.612) & (-5.224) & (-1.771) \\
 umd & -12.971^{***} & -12.961^{***} & -13.173^{***} & -10.169^{**} & -12.666^{***} & -11.162 & -16.585^{***} & -13.009^{***} & -13.482^{***} & -17.187^{***} & -9.915 & -11.852^{**} & -17.187^{***} & -4.792 \\
 & (-3.361) & (-3.361) & (-3.263) & (-2.342) & (-3.228) & (-1.385) & (-3.762) & (-2.822) & (-3.392) & (-3.748) & (-1.451) & (-2.588) & (-3.748) & (-0.596) \\
 SBBB\_l1 & 0.127 \\
 & (0.779) \\
 HHHH\_l1 & & -0.195 \\
 & & (-1.201) \\
 LuUU\_l1 & & & 0.427^{*} \\
 & & & (1.749) \\
 UMMM\_l1 & & & & 0.859 \\
 & & & & (0.597) \\
 CCC\_l1 & & & & & -0.423 \\
 & & & & & (-0.643) \\
 FFFF\_l1 & & & & & & -0.323 \\
 & & & & & & (-0.801) \\
 VVV\_l1 & & & & & & & 0.473 \\
 & & & & & & & (0.176) \\
 AAAA\_l1 & & & & & & & & -0.528 \\
 & & & & & & & & (-0.326) \\
 IIII\_l1 & & & & & & & & & -1.470 \\
 & & & & & & & & & (-1.169) \\
 CRCR\_l1 & & & & & & & & & & -0.127 \\
 & & & & & & & & & & (-0.113) & & & & \\
 MS\_l1 & & & & & & & & & & & -0.501^{*} \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & (-1.673) & & & \\
 SENT1\_L1 & & & & & & & & & & & & -0.473^{**} \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & (-2.326) & & \\
 SENT2\_l1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & -0.025 \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & (-0.113) & \\
 SENT3\_l1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & -0.881^{**} \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & (-2.177) \\
 \midrule
 \_cons & 0.917^{***} & 0.905^{***} & 0.756^{***} & 0.353 & 1.347^{**} & 0.644 & 1.140^{**} & 1.272 & 1.859^{**} & 1.117 & 0.709^{**} & 0.957^{***} & 1.010^{***} & 0.619 \\
 & (5.536) & (5.462) & (3.666) & (0.283) & (2.109) & (1.611) & (2.043) & (1.382) & (2.404) & (1.150) & (2.534) & (4.704) & (4.500) & (1.584) \\
 Obs. & \mc{618} & \mc{618} & \mc{530} & \mc{479} & \mc{610} & \mc{90} & \mc{335} & \mc{365} & \mc{582} & \mc{266} & \mc{144} & \mc{365} & \mc{266} & \mc{90} \\
 R\textsuperscript{2} & 0.184 & 0.185 & 0.211 & 0.177 & 0.188 & 0.463 & 0.288 & 0.228 & 0.188 & 0.323 & 0.394 & 0.240 & 0.323 & 0.488 \\ 
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{15}{l}{T-values are in parenthesis. $^{***}\ p<0.01$, $^{**}\ p<0.05$, $^{*}\ p<0.1$} 
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```